# Unity and Airconsole

Tags: unity-game-engine, airconsole

I want to develop a game by using Unity gaming engine with airconsole plugin but till now i am not able to find any good tutorial to start working on it please if some one knows a good tutorial please let me know.
It will be agreat great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the [Unity Guide](http://developers.airconsole.com/#/guides/unity), which provides instructions on how to get started with Unity/AirConsole specifically.

Looking at the Basic Example scene and script (which comes with the plugin) will also help you figure out how the AirConsole functions can and should be used within Unity.

If you are completely unfamiliar with the Unity Game Engine, I recommend starting with generic Unity tutorials and then moving to AirConsole when you have the basics figured out.

Answer (score 0):

It's on their website: http://developers.airconsole.com/#/getting_started

A simple google search would've given you the same result

Comment: I am searching for a step by step guide. I am a newbie